# Is restarting an activity the only solution here?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

I have two `Fragment` classes and a `dragEventListner` class in an activity. Each fragment class has a `imageScroller` which is controlled by their own `imageAdapter` and `listArray`. `Fragment1` class has a set of images which is dragged and dropped into `Fragment2`. Images are read from the sd-card. When an image is dropped, I update the `listArray` of `Fragment2` and call `<adapter>.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Image gets added to the list (as I see in file explorer) but the changes don't show up in the activity (i.e. I can't see the dropped image) until I restart the app. However, I tried restarting the app by `finish()` and then calling an already saved intent. The code below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

This doesn't work best due to popup crash message `Unfortunately, app has stopped working` and then resuming. Is restarting the app only solution to this or I still have other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter of the imagescroller?  i have something similar in my project:

```
mAdapter.setArticles(ArticleList);
mPager.setAdapter( mAdapter );


ArticleList.add (0, ProcessXMLArticle(ArticleSearched)); 
mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where mPAger is a view pager, i just add an item to the list and call notify() in your case mPager would be your imageScroller

Comment: Yes I used the same way. But the control, once in DragListner, never goes back to Fragment2 class. So the image never shows up.